# How Skip press Enter to continue in shell Command using python

Tags: python, linux

How can u skip press enter to continue after desplaying it i know how to skip press Yes /No by typing -y for exemple but what it's the solution when it's Enter ??
Thanks .

Comment: And the reason that you didn't include code is...? Did you check what Enter, on its own, submits?

Answer (score 2):

If you're ok with using the command line, you might find the `yes` command helpful. You can have it repeat a string over and over, so you could use `yes '\n' | yourcommand` to have it repeatedly press the newline key while running your command.

```
$ man yes

YES(1)                    BSD General Commands Manual                   YES(1)

NAME
     yes -- be repetitively affirmative

SYNOPSIS
     yes [expletive]

DESCRIPTION
     yes outputs expletive, or, by default, ``y'', forever.

HISTORY
     The yes command appeared in 4.0BSD.

4th Berkeley Distribution        June 6, 1993        4th Berkeley Distribution
```

Comment: I don't think `yes` supports C-style escapes like `\n` (at least not portably) but just `yes ''` might well work.